# Prove independence of subset of mutually independent sets

Tags: probability

I want to prove that $ P(C \cap D) = P(C)*P(D)$ with the assumption that $C \subseteq A \quad \text{and} \quad  D \subseteq B \quad \text{ and the events A and B are mutually independent such that } P(A \cap B ) = P (A)*P(B)$

Answer (score 2):

This is not always true. Toss a fair $4$-sided die with the sides labelled $1,2,3,4$.

Let $A$ be the event the number rolled is even, and let $B$ be the event the number is $\le 2$. Then $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Let $C$ be the event the number rolled is $2$, and let $D=C$. Then $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$, but $C$ and $D$ are not independent.

Comment: I have the events A,B,C,D are mutually independent such that $P (A \cap B \cap C \cap D) = P(A)P(B)P(C)P(D)$ and I want to prove events $(A \cap B)$ and  $(C \cap D)$ are also mutually independent such that $P((A \cap B) \cap (C \cap D)) = P (A \cap B) P(C \cap D)$

Comment: Your first condition, is it mutually independent or is it the probability assertion? (They do not have the same meaning.) I need to know precisely what you want to show.